# Validations not working in MVC3?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, validation

This is how my model looks

```
      public class ProjectModel
      {
       public static List<ProjectModel> GetList { get; set; }
       public Int16 ID { get; set; }
       [Required(ErrorMessage = "ProjectName is required")]
       public string projectName { get; set; }
       [Required(ErrorMessage = "Description is required")]
       public string Description { get; set; }
       [Required(ErrorMessage = "Status is required")]
       public string status { get; set; }  
      }
```

This is how Controller Looks

```
          #region Insert New Project
    //
    //View for adding new Projects/
    //
    [AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Get)]
    public ActionResult Create()
    {
        ViewBag.Status = new SelectList(GetStatus(), "Status", "Status");
        return View();
    }

     [AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
    public ActionResult Create(ProjectModel model,string Status)
    {
        // var modelList = new List<ProjectModel>();
        using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("Data Source=LMIT-0039;Initial Catalog=BugTracker;Integrated Security=True"))
        {
            conn.Open();
            SqlCommand insertcommande = new SqlCommand("Sp_AddNewProject", conn);
            insertcommande.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            insertcommande.Parameters.Add("@ProjectName", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = model.projectName;
            insertcommande.Parameters.Add("@Description", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = model.Description;
            insertcommande.Parameters.Add("@Status", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value =Status;
            insertcommande.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
        return RedirectToAction("Create");
    }


      #region To Edit th Existing Project Record
    //
    //View For displaying the record to be edited/
    //
    [AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Get)]
    public ActionResult Edit(int id, ProjectModel updatemodel)
    {
        ViewBag.Status = new SelectList(GetStatus(), "Status", "Status");
        SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection("Data Source=LMIT-0039;Initial Catalog=BugTracker;Integrated Security=True");
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Select ProjectId,projectName,Description,status From Projects Where ProjectId=" + id, cn);
        cn.Open();
        SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        if (dr.Read())
        {
            //if ( dr[0]) != DBNull.Value) 
            updatemodel.ID = Convert.ToInt16(dr["ProjectId"]);
            updatemodel.projectName = dr["projectName"].ToString();
            updatemodel.Description = dr["Description"].ToString();
            updatemodel.status = dr["status"].ToString();
        }
        else
        {
            dr.Close();
        }
        dr.Close();
        cn.Close();
        return View(updatemodel);
    }
    //
    //Action for editing the record which is in view/
    //
    [AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
    public ActionResult Edit(ProjectModel updatemodel, FormCollection form, int id,string Status)
    {

        SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection("Data Source=LMIT-0039;Initial Catalog=BugTracker;Integrated Security=True");
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("UpdateProject", cn);
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        cn.Open();
        cmd.Parameters.Add("ProjectId", SqlDbType.Int).Value = updatemodel.ID;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("projectName", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = updatemodel.projectName;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("Description", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = updatemodel.Description;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("status", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = Status;
        cn.Close();
        return View(updatemodel);
    }

    #endregion
```

and this is how my aspx page looks

```
     <% using (Html.BeginForm())
     { %>
     <%-- <form action="Create.aspx" method="post"></form>--%>
    <%:Html.ValidationSummary(true)%>
    <fieldset>
    <legend style="color:Orange; font-weight:bolder;">AddNew Project</legend>

  <div class="editor-label" style="color:Orange; font-weight:bolder;">
        <%: Html.LabelFor(model => model.projectName)%>
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
       <%:Html.EditorFor(model => model.projectName)%>
      <%: Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.projectName)%>
    </div>

    <div class="editor-label" style="color:Orange; font-weight:bolder;">
       <%:Html.LabelFor(model => model.Description)%>
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
       <%:Html.EditorFor(model => model.Description)%>
       <%:Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Description)%>
    </div>
    <div class="editor-label" style="color:Orange; font-weight:bolder;">
    <%:Html.LabelFor(model => model.status)%>
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
    <%:Html.DropDownList("Status")%>
    <%:Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.status)%>
    </div>
    <p>
        <input type="submit" value="Create" style="color:Orange; font-weight:bolder;"/>
        </p>
    </fieldset>
 <%} %>
```

My problem is Validations are not fired In my Create new Page when i click submit button
but validations are geting before even i cilck in my edit page can any one tell me where am i doing wrong

or there is any other method to provide validations

Comment: You comment makes no sense.  You say validations are not fired, then you say validations are happening before the page loads?  Please clearly ask your question.

Comment: @MystereMan validations are not fired in my Create page but In my edit page Validations are fired at my page load..i mentioned this

Comment: whats the name of the view you have added in the question ?

Comment: @Yasser Create for edit and the html is same with different views

Answer (score 0):

You aren't actually checking to see if any validations have failed.  In your controller methods where you post, you need to have a check:

```
if (ModelState.IsValid) {
    // do your work

    return RedirectToAction("WhereYouWantToGoAfterwards");
}

return View(model);
```

EDIT:

As I said above, you're not actually checking for errors in your code.  However, the effect you are seeing that is different between the Create and Edit is that in the Edit, you return a View(), but in the Create you RedirectToAction.  Redirect's clear the ModelState, so you would not see any errors.

You still need to check if the ModelState.IsValid before you start doing work based on the data.  Otherwise, you're going to run into a lot of trouble.